# Count the interval between two dates only if it's more than 4s

Tags: php

I'm facing a little problem, and i need your help :)

I explain : 
I have an array of 2 dates like this :

```
DateMin : 16/03/2016 19:12:08   DateMax : 16/03/2016 19:18:29
DateMin : 16/03/2016 19:12:08   DateMax : 16/03/2016 19:18:30
DateMin : 16/03/2016 19:12:09   DateMax : 16/03/2016 19:18:30
DateMin : 16/03/2016 19:12:09   DateMax : 16/03/2016 19:18:31
DateMin : 07/04/2016 12:14:21   DateMax : 07/04/2016 12:31:03
```

What i would like to do is to count the interval beetween 2 dates, only if this interval is more than 4seconds.

Here is what i'm trying to do  :

```
foreach($res as $r){
            if(isset($output[$r['DATE']])) {
                $dateBefore = null;
                $dateSql = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y G:i:s",$r['DATE']);
                if($dateBefore == null){
                    $dateBefore = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y G:i:s",$r['DATE']);
                }
                $interval = $dateSql->diff($dateBefore);
                if($interval->format('%s') > 4){
                    $dateBefore = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y G:i:s",$r['DATE']);
                    $output[$r['DATE']] += intval($interval->format('%s'));
                }
            }
            else
                $output[$r['DATE']] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: And what happens if the difference is 4 seconds or less?

Comment: And what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I put the value at 0, i don't care about the difference if it's less than 4 seconds.
The problem i'm facing, is that i don't know why i have too much values or too less

Comment: Your code is not matching the arrays you specified?

Comment: If you get the dates from SQL (and you seem to), use the SQL server's date arithmetic. It'll be faster and easier written, along the lines of `SUM(date1-date2) WHERE date1-date2 > 4`

Comment: No no, my code is matching my array, but i don't know why, 
I fail to count the time interval between my two dates and place as the value in a new table, with as example
array (618) {[ "03/16/2016"] => int (57) [ "20/03/2016"] => int (58) [ "07/04/2016"] => int (0)
And the int are the interval between 2 date (start and end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you need to change

```
if($interval->format('%s') > 4)
```

as

```
if($interval->format('%R%a') > 4)
```

and

```
$output[$r['DATE']] += intval($interval->format('%s'));
```

as

```
$output[$r['DATE']] += intval($interval->format('%R%a'));
```